# How to append a row from datatable1 to a datatable2 with registers ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

```
I need to append a row from databla1 to datatable2 that has already rows, I tried to importrow(), clone(), but I cant' find the solution:

The datatable1 has this structure:

name | surname | iddepartment | address | phone1 | phone2 | country | cp | birthdate |
```

And the datatable2 is a public datatable created inside a class:

```
Public Shared datable2 As New DataTable
```

I have this code:

```
 Dim datatable1 As DataTable = getdata("myQuery")
```

I tried to do this but I get an error:

```
Dim newRow= datatable1.Rows(0)

myClass.datatable2.rows.add(newRow)
```

How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand.

VB.NET Sample :

```
    'db query result'

    table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("surname", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("iddepartment", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("phone1", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("phone2", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("country", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("cp", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("birthdate", GetType(DateTime))

    'column set'
    Dim table2 As DataTable = table

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    'add dummy data'
    For index = 1 To 10
        'instance new dataRow '
        Dim dr As DataRow = table2.NewRow
        dr("Name") = "Jack"
        dr("surname") = "Daniels"
        dr("iddepartment") = i
        dr("phone1") = "099999"
        dr("phone2") = "09999"
        dr("country") = "USA"
        dr("cp") = "-"
        dr("birthdate") = New DateTime

        table2.Rows.Add(dr)

        i = i + 1
    Next

    'each table2 rows'
    For Each rowItem As DataRow In table2.Rows

        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("Name"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("surname"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("iddepartment"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("phone1"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("phone2"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("country"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("cp"))
        Console.WriteLine(rowItem("birthdate"))

    Next
    Console.Read()
```

Datatable Example Source Link : https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-vbnet

Comment: I tried your code, I get this error message:  The input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Comment: But my problem is that the table 2 has already rows and I want only to add a row from table1 to table2 , so I can't put : table2 = table

Comment: @Esraa_92 OK. I understand your problem. I'm changed my example, please look and try. Please review DataRow sample. I hope it helps